# What does IDS in iOS/watchOS debug logs stand for?

Tags: ios, debugging, internal, watchos

I recently got a request from Apple to gather IDS logs for a bug report I filed. They sent me a Continuity debugging profile which gathers IDS logs. But what does IDS stand for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poring through the IDS logs I found reference to an "identityservicesd". I think it is safe to say that IDS stands for **ID**entity**S**ervices. Who knows exactly what it does but safe to say I think it handles the identity of devices engaged in a Continuity operation.